# Image and Text DIV as internal link for SEO

Tags: seo, hyperlink

How do I makee effective internal links?

Currently using

```
<a href="page.html"><div><imgsrc>sometext<div></a>
```

i.e. I have a link on div which has image and some text. Is this a good practice?

Comment: oops... code missing=> Currently doing.

<a href = "page.php"><div><imgsrc>SomeText</div></a>

how to improve it??

Comment: I read that it's valid in HTML5. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6484795/div-within-a-seo-optimization

Answer (score 1):

This is sloppy HTML for sure. The `<DIV>` tag has no value for SEO. It's also a block level element which means inline elements, like `<a>` and `<img>` should be contained within it. Not the other way around.

Links, whether internal or external, are helpful for SEO purposes as they help to confer the meaning of the recipient page. Your goal is to use keywords that describe the recipient page as anchor text in the link. Don't stuff keywords in there as that will only hurt you. But if your content is good the anchor text should automatically have keywords in it.

`<IMG>`, whether wrapped in a link or not, doesn't really convey much for SEO. The alt attribute does have some SEO value but it is minute at best so it shouldn't be an area of focus. Plus it should only serve as alternative content if the image fails to download or is purposely  not rendered (i.e. screen readers). Once again, stuffing this with keywords does not benefit you.

Comment: well.. ofcourse, the a tag is in an outer div, its not floating of its own :) not satisfied with the answer, it didnt tell me what i want to know, i.e. if crawlers shall be able to access pages easily if i use links like above, or give me a better way. i know abt keywords and alt, no need to mention that....
Thanks for the help anyways.
and the code ain`t sloppy, my dear.. world`s no 4 website uses this kind og links.

Comment: @saurabh First, if you wanted to know something different then you should have asked for that. Second, the code **is** sloppy; it's invalid to have block-level elements like `<div>` inside inline elements like `<a>`. Third, this should have been asked on [Pro Webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com) instead of here since it's not a programming question.